# awk to add extracted prefix from file to filename

Tags: bash, awk

The below `awk` execute as is, but it renames fields within each matching file that matches `$p` (which is extracted from each text file) instead of adding `$x` which is the prefix to add (from $1 of rename) to each filename in the directory. Each `$x` is followed by a`_` the the filename. I can see in the `echo $p` the correct value to use in the lookup for `$2` is extracted but each file in the directory is unchanged. Not every file in the `rename` will be in the directory, but it will always have a match to `$p`. Maybe there is a better way as I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you :).

**rename**  `tab-delimeted`

```
00-0000     File-01
00-0001     File-02
00-0002     File-03
00-0003     File-04
```

**file1**

```
File-01_xxxx.txt
```

**file2**

```
File-02_yyyy.txt
```

**desired output**

```
00-0000_File-01-xxxx.txt
00-0001_File-02-yyyy.txt
```

**bash**

```
for file1 in /path/to/folders/*.txt
do
# Grab file prefix
  bname=`basename $file1` # strip of path
  p="$(echo $bname|cut -d_ -f1,1)" # remove after second underscore
  echo $p
# add prefix to matching file
  awk -v var="$p" '$2~var{x=$1}(NR=x){print $x"_",$bname}' $file1 rename OFS="\t" > tmp && mv tmp $file1
done
```

Comment: I think the example file names "_" and "-" values are inconsistent.  Also, if you're not changing the contents of the files `awk` is probably not your best bet.  It will also fail with empty files.

Comment: The filenames have multiple `-` hyphens but only one `_` underscore in them. That is the naming convention for older files so I just keep it. Each file will have data in it. Maybe `sed` is a better choice? Thank you :).

Comment: `File-02-yyyy.txt` doesn't fit the bill unless it's a typo. You don't need to read the files (`awk` and `sed` unneeded), here `bash` programming is perhaps better alternative: `mv $path/$f $path/$prefix_"$f`.  Lookup prefix from the map by filename `${f%_*}`

Comment: That was a typo, corrected... sorry, I will give it a try :).

Comment: What's the purpose of the file named `rename`? Whey not just figure out the new number from the previous number minus 1?

Comment: Do you want to rename a list of files (based on the content of the file 'rename') or do you want to add/change the content of the file? Or both? The description says, you want to rename, but the awk command reads two files and replaces the file with the output. Within the awk-script you are using `$bname`, which is a bash variable not known to `awk`.

Comment: The `File-01_xxxx` and `File-02_yyyy` are examples names and may not always be incremental so I use `rename` to store the filenames and prefix. I am only trying to add the prefix in `rename` to the filename, and my attempt changed the contents of it. That is not intended. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script :

```
touch File-01-azer.txt
touch File-02-ytrf.txt
touch File-03-fdfd.txt
touch File-04-dfrd.txt

while read p f;
do
    f=$(ls $f*)
    mv ${f} "${p}_${f}"
done << EEE
00-0000    File-01
00-0001    File-02
00-0002    File-03
00-0003    File-04
EEE

ls -1
```

outputs :

```
00-0000_File-01-azer.txt
00-0001_File-02-ytrf.txt
00-0002_File-03-fdfd.txt
00-0003_File-04-dfrd.txt
```

You can use a file as input using `done < rename_map.txt` or `cat rename_map.txt | while`