# How to specify a file prefix in gawk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I am trying to identify file extensions from a list of filenames extracted from a floppy disk image. The problem is different from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48389205/2348597) where files are already extracted from the disk image. I'm new to `gawk` so maybe it is not the right tool.

```
ls Sounddsk2.img -a1 > allfilenames
```

The command above creates the list of filenames shown below.

```
flute.pt
flute.ss
flute.vc
guitar.pt
guitar.ss
guitar.vc
```

The `gawk` command below identifies files ending in `.ss`

```
cat allfilenames | gawk '/[fluteguitar].ss/' > ssfilenames
```

This would be fine when there are just a few known file names. How do I specify a file prefix in a more generic form?

Comment: Why are you creating a file of all file names using `ls` and then using a tool like awk to just get the ones ending in `.ss` instead of just doing `printf '%s\n' *.ss` or similar in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

with the regex you come `/[fluteguitar].ss/`, this matches on lines having one of these characters in it `f`, `l`, `u`, `e`, `g`, `i`, `t`, `a` and `r` (specified within bracket expression `[...]`,duplicated characters count only once) followed by any single character (except newline here) that a single un-escaped dot `.` matches, then double `ss` in any place of a line.

you need to restrict the matching by using the start `^` and end `$` of line anchors, as well as using the group of match.

```
awk '/^(flute|guitar)\.ss$/' allFilesName> ssFileNames
```

to filter only two files names matched with `flute.ss` and/or `guitar.ss`. The group match `(...|...)` is matches on any one of regexpes separated by the pipe as saying logical OR.

if these are just prefixes and to match any files beginning with these characters and end with `.ss`, use:

```
awk '/^(flute|guitar).*\.ss$/' allFilesName> ssFileNames
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying start and end anchors. So '/^[a-zA-Z0-9].*\.ss$/' would be more generic than '/^(flute|guitar).*\.ss$/' ? because I used only flute and guitar as examples of prefix names but there are many others.

Comment: @Greg it's depends on what characters you want match, not about generic, non-generic things.

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone can suggest a better one this seems to be the most generic way to express this. It will work for any prefix filename spelt with uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers

```
cat allfilenames | gawk '/[a-zA-Z0-9].ss/' > ssfilenames
```

---

**Edit**

αғsнιη's [first suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67564412/2348597) and jetchisel's comment prompted me to try using `gawk` without using `cat`.

```
gawk '/^([a-zA-Z0-9])\.ss$/' allfilenames > ssfilenames
```

and this also worked

```
gawk '/[a-zA-Z0-9]\.ss/' allfilenames > ssfilenames
```

Comment: No need to use the `cat` , `gawk` can parse the file just fine.

Comment: there is nothing here for GNU awk specifc, all awk does the job what you want. and about the `[a-zA-Z0-9]\.ss` similarly I have explained that what it does. it will match in thing like `سلام14Hello.ss`, so you need start/end anchors to avoid that

Comment: Afshim, so /^ and $/ are the start/end anchors. Correct ? and the brackets ( and ) are they essential ?

Comment: @αғsнιη, got it (with cut'n'paste :)

Comment: @Greg copy'n'paste :    )

Answer (score 1):

Please use `find` command to deal with matching of names of files, with your shown samples you could try following. You could run this command on directory itself and you need not to store file names into a file and then use `awk` for it.

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/(flute|guitar)\.ss$'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `find` command's capability to add regextype in it(using `egrep` style here); where giving regex to match file names `fulte` OR `guitar` and make sure its ending with ss here.

Comment: Ravinder, does egrep have advantages over using gawk ?

Comment: @Greg, experts always advice not to parse ls output with awk or any other language they advise to use find command. egrep here is just using its regex style actual work is done by find command. Please do let me know if this helps you, thank you

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use grep with `-E` for extended regexp and use an alter alternation to match either flute or guitar.

```
ls Sounddsk2.img -a1 | grep -E "^(flute|guitar)\.ss$" > ssfilenames
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(flute|guitar)` Match either flute or guitar
- `\.ss` Match `.ss`
- `$` End of string

The file *ssfilenames* contains:

```
flute.ss
guitar.ss
```

Comment: The fourth bird, does grep have advantages over using gawk ?